# Как вывести html списки из зависимых моделей

Tags: python, django

Модели:

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, db_column='comp_name')
    comp_house_count=models.IntegerField(db_column='comp_house_count')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comp_name

class House(models.Model):
    house_addr=models.CharField(max_length=264,db_column='House_addr')
    geo_lat = models.FloatField(db_column='geo_lat')
    geo_lon = models.FloatField(db_column='geo_lon')
    comp_id= models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.house_addr
```

Вьюхи:

```py
# def Comp(request):
#     complist = Company.objects.order_by('comp_house_count')
#     # comp_dict = {complist:houselist}
#     content={"complist":complist,}
#     return render(request,'Apptwo/map.html',content)

def Houselist(request):
    houselist = House.objects.order_by('comp_id')
    content={"houselist":houselist}
    return render(request,'AppTwo/map.html',content)
    введите сюда код
```

Попробовал вот так:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Тут будет карта</h1>
    <div class="Ctable">
      {% if houselist %}
        {%for house in houselist%}
        <select>
          <option>{{house.comp_id}}</option>
        </select>
            <ol>
              <li>{{house.house_addr}}</li>
            </ol>
          {%endfor%}
      {%else%}
      <p>No companies found</p>
      {%endif%}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Хотел получить структуру:
Выбор компании в SELECT
отображает Список домов  компании по comp_id
Но не получил

Подскажите, как сделать, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, вы хотели сделать это. Как видите - проблема в том, что select назодился в цикле, а не вне.

Если ответ не подходит - уточните что вам нужно

```
    <div class="Ctable">
      {% if houselist %}

      <select>
        {%for house in houselist%}
        <option value="{{house.comp_id}}">{{house.house_addr}}</option>
        {%endfor%}
      </select>
      {%else%}
      <p>No companies found</p>
      {%endif%}

    </div>
```